# How to set BusyIndicator to the center of window?

Tags: wpf, busyindicator

WPF:
set BusyIndicator to the center of window

Answer (score 1):

Use `HorizontalAlignment ="Center"` and `VerticalAlignment="Center"` attached properties.

For example:

```
<Windows>
    <Grid>

    <extToolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="True" HorizontalAlignment ="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In case you want a control to be over everything on the Windows, I think you should place it inside of a popup and control the popups position from code.

As a last resort, you can put BusyIndicator to a separate boardeless WPF window to top it over the WindowsFormsHost.

In order to keep a popup sticky to its parent, just call popup.Activate() each time your parent Windows is activated. This way, if some other applications windows goes over yours, both, popup and the parent will be beneath the currently active windows. The moment user activates the parent window, it will call activate on the popup, so that it appears they are stuck together. This is rather a trick, I know. Maybe someone has a better solution.

Comment: Those are not attached properties and setting `VerticalAlignment` in a (vertical) `StackPanel` does nothing.

Comment: Thanks Maxim. It fails if there are other controls eg grid, WindowsFormsHost. I need BusyIndicator on top of everything and be the center of the window, and tied to the window. Thanks.

Comment: @WPF new - I would use a Popup as a host for BusyIndicator. That would allow you to have it over WindowsFormsHost.

Comment: Hi Maxim, I tried popup. It behinds WindowsFormsHost and it is not tied to the owner window and shows up every window. Thanks.

Comment: @WPF new - if a WPF control is on the same windows as WindowsFormsHost - there is no way you can top a WPF control over WinForms one, since it neverminds the z-order. That is why I recommend popup, since it is detached from your WPF window, therefore can go over WinFormsHost. You can just place the BusyIndicator in a boarderless windows to be sure it is on top.

Comment: How to have the popup tied to its parent and not show up on other windows? Thanks.